# Script auto make selection snap to added guides line

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop-script

I need a script for photoshop which can create a square or rectangular selection (use rectangular marquee tool) and it will snap to the guides line, no matter the position of the guides, sometimes with 2 guides sometimes I will add 4 guides. Or it'll be ok if the script make a selection from the guide to the bottom of the photo.

[make selection snap to guides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zalH4.png)

Here are some other options that I'm expecting
[make selection 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1GQr.png)
[make selection 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8ssW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here script that creates a rectangular selection:

```
// Get the active document
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// Get the guides
var guides = doc.guides;

// Get the first horizontal and vertical guides
var hGuide1 = guides[0];
var vGuide1 = guides[1];

// Get the second horizontal and vertical guides (if they exist)
var hGuide2 = guides.length > 2 ? guides[2] : null;
var vGuide2 = guides.length > 3 ? guides[3] : null;

// Calculate the selection coordinates based on the guides
var x1 = vGuide1.direction == Direction.VERTICAL ? vGuide1.coordinate : hGuide1.coordinate;
var y1 = hGuide1.direction == Direction.HORIZONTAL ? hGuide1.coordinate : vGuide1.coordinate;
var x2 = vGuide2 != null && vGuide2.direction == Direction.VERTICAL ? vGuide2.coordinate : doc.width.as("px");
var y2 = hGuide2 != null && hGuide2.direction == Direction.HORIZONTAL ? hGuide2.coordinate : doc.height.as("px");

// Create the rectangular selection
doc.selection.select([[x1, y1], [x2, y1], [x2, y2], [x1, y2]], SelectionType.REPLACE, 0, false);
```

To run it, create a file with the extension jsx. For example: script.jsx

Then File->Scripts->Browse... select the file script.jsx

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Please mark answer as approved

Answer (score 0):

First up, should understand that SO is not a code writing service. Also, you should include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code.

Ok, on with your question:

You can get the rectangular coordinates of a selection with selection bounds.
It's just a case of adding a horizontal or vertical guide to those bounds:
The code for the guides was taken from the [script listener.](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html)

```
// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // OFF 

// Top, Left, Bottom, Right

var sb = get_selection_bounds();
if (sb != undefined)
{
  add_guide(sb[0], "v");
  add_guide(sb[1], "h");
  add_guide(sb[2], "v");
  add_guide(sb[3], "h");
}


// Set Display Dialogs back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // NORMAL



function add_guide(dist, dir)
{
    var vert = true;
    if (dir.toLowerCase() == "v") vert = true;
    if (dir.toLowerCase() == "h") vert = false;

    var idMk = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
    var desc1583 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idNw = charIDToTypeID( "Nw  " );
    var desc1584 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idPstn = charIDToTypeID( "Pstn" );
    var idPxl = charIDToTypeID( "#Pxl" );
    desc1584.putUnitDouble( idPstn, idPxl, dist );
    var idOrnt = charIDToTypeID( "Ornt" );
    var idOrnt = charIDToTypeID( "Ornt" );
    if (vert == true)
    {
        var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID( "Vrtc" );
        desc1584.putEnumerated( idOrnt, idOrnt, idVrtc );
    }
    else
    {
        var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID( "Hrzn" );
        desc1584.putEnumerated( idOrnt, idOrnt, idHrzn );
    }
    var idKnd = charIDToTypeID( "Knd " );
    var idKnd = charIDToTypeID( "Knd " );
    var idDcmn = charIDToTypeID( "Dcmn" );
    desc1584.putEnumerated( idKnd, idKnd, idDcmn );
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref457 = new ActionReference();
    var idDcmn = charIDToTypeID( "Dcmn" );
    ref457.putIdentifier( idDcmn, 1015 );
    var idGd = charIDToTypeID( "Gd  " );
    ref457.putIndex( idGd, 1 );
    desc1584.putReference( idnull, ref457 );
    var idGd = charIDToTypeID( "Gd  " );
    desc1583.putObject( idNw, idGd, desc1584 );
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var ref458 = new ActionReference();
    var idGd = charIDToTypeID( "Gd  " );
    ref458.putClass( idGd );
    desc1583.putReference( idnull, ref458 );
    var idguideTarget = stringIDToTypeID( "guideTarget" );
    var idguideTarget = stringIDToTypeID( "guideTarget" );
    var idguideTargetCanvas = stringIDToTypeID( "guideTargetCanvas" );
    desc1583.putEnumerated( idguideTarget, idguideTarget, idguideTargetCanvas );
    executeAction( idMk, desc1583, DialogModes.NO );
}



// function GET SELECTION BOUNDS ()
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
function get_selection_bounds()
{
  try
  {
    var t = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[0]);
    var l = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[1]);
    var b = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[2]);
    var r = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[3]);

    // T, L, B, R
    // return the results as an array
    return [t, l, b, r];
 }
 catch(eek)
 {
   return undefined;
 }

}
```

[image: selection creates guides]

Comment: thanks for your help
idk why but it doesn't work :(

Comment: The script will only work with a selection. Also, it won't won't if you've got no documents open.